# Is RSA_NO_PAD algorithm different in C(openssl) and Javacard

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, javacard

I have a 128 byte RSA Key. I have encrypted data of length 128 bytes in the javacard applet using the public key and decrypted it in the C application using private key of the same key pair. The resultant data is different than the original data. What is the reason for it?

Javacard Code

```
asymCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_RSA_NOPAD, false);
asymCipher.init(PkTCA, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
asymCipher.doFinal(data, (short)0, (short)data.length, encrypted, (short)0);
```

C Code

```
int padding = RSA_NO_PADDING;

int private_decrypt(unsigned char * enc_data,int data_len,unsigned char * key, unsigned char *decrypted)
{
    RSA * rsa = createRSA(key,0);
    int  result = RSA_private_decrypt(data_len,enc_data,decrypted,rsa,padding);
    return result;
}

encrypted_length = private_decrypt(PkAIKR,strlen(PkAIKR),privateKeyTCA,PkAIKR_dec);
```

Comment: Give us your RSA key and all data.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is probably larger than the modulus when *interpreted* as a unsigned big endian integer value. RSA in the end works on numbers, not bytes. If the value is larger then the value will first be converted into the value Y = X % N where X is the original value and N is the modulus (and % is the modulus or remainder operation).

So you can only encrypt data that represents a number between 0 and N, otherwise your result is ambiguous (it can be either Y or Y + N). A useful trick is to make sure that your input data length is at least one bit smaller than the modulus length (although often the complete most significant / leftmost byte is set to either `00` or `01`).

---

Note that - with the possible exception of RSA-KEM - using RSA without PKCS#1 v1.5 padding or OAEP padding is *insecure*.